# Why is SoftwareLicenseId null in the POST method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am updating the data using my `Create` view in my `ASP.NET MVC` project. When I get the data to display in the `Create` view from the `GET` method, I see that I am getting the correct `SoftwareLicenseId` from the database in the `Model`. However, when I correct the other fields and save the data, I see that the same `Model`, now with the corrected data in `POST` method shows `SoftwareLicenseId` to be `null`. How can I correct that?

```
// GET
public IActionResult Create(int? Id)
{
    // Creating/Entering new data
    if(Id == null)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // Updating existing data. Control coming when edit button pressed
    else
    {
        var softwareLicensesDetails = _context.SoftwareLicenses.Where(sl => sl.SoftwareLicenseId == Id).SingleOrDefault();

        return View(softwareLicensesDetails);
    }

}

// ~/SoftwareLicenses/Create
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(SoftwareLicenses softwareLicenses)
{
    try
    {
        //SoftwareLicenseId not present -> New Data. Therefore inserting.

        if (softwareLicenses.SoftwareLicenseId <= 0)          
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(softwareLicenses);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Details");
            }
        }

        // SoftwareLicenseId already there in database -> Data present in database. Therefore, updating.
        else
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                softwareLicenses.SoftwareLicenseId = Id;

                _context.Update(softwareLicenses);
                _context.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Details");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
    return View(NotFound());
}
```

**Edit**

View:

```
 <div class="card-body card-padding" id="softwareLicensesCreate">
    <form method="post" asp-action="Create" asp-controller="SoftwareLicenses">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
                <div class="input-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <label asp-for="ProductName" class="fg-label" for="productName">Product Name</label>
                        <input asp-for="ProductName" class="form-control" id="productName" name="productName" required />
                        <span asp-validation-for="ProductName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p class="c-black f-500 no-margin">Purchase Date</p>
                <div class="input-group fg-float">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-calendar"></i></span>
                    <div class="dtp-container">
                        <input type="text" asp-for="PurchaseDate" class="form-control date-picker" placeholder="Click here..." id="purchaseDate" name="purchaseDate" required data-date-form />
                        <span asp-validation-for="PurchaseDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row m-t-20">
            <div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
                <div class="input-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <input asp-for="Cost" class="form-control" id="cost" name="cost" required />
                        <label asp-for="Cost" class="fg-label" for="cost">Cost</label>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Cost" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
                <div class="fg-line form-chose">
                    <label class="fg-label" for="subscriptionType">Subscription Type: </label>
                    <select id="subscriptionType" asp-for="SubscriptionType" data-placeholder="Select Subscription Type" class="chosen disabledropdowncntrl" name="subscriptionType" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Subscription Type</option>
                        <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
                        <option value="Yearly">Yearly</option>
                        <option value="OneTime">One-Time</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row m-t-20">
            <div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
                <div class="input-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <input asp-for="RenewalCost" class="form-control" id="renewalCost" name="renewalCost" />
                        <label asp-for="RenewalCost" class="fg-label" for="renewalCost">Renewal Cost</label>
                        <span asp-validation-for="RenewalCost" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
                <div class="input-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <input asp-for="LicenseKey" class="form-control" id="licenseKey" name="licenseKey" />
                        <label asp-for="LicenseKey" class="fg-label" for="licenseKey">License Key</label>
                        <span asp-validation-for="LicenseKey" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row m-t-20">
            <div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
                <div class="input-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <input asp-for="URL" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" />
                        <label asp-for="URL" class="fg-label" for="url">URL</label>
                        <span asp-validation-for="URL" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
                <div class="input-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" />
                        <label asp-for="Username" class="fg-label" for="username">Username</label>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row m-t-20">
            <div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
                <div class="input-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" />
                        <label asp-for="Password" class="fg-label" for="password">Password</label>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
                <div class="toggle-switch toggle-switch-demo">
                    <label for="InUse" class="ts-label">In Use?</label>
                    <input id="inUseRadio" type="checkbox" class="disablecntrl" asp-for="InUse" checked/>
                    <label for="InUse" class="checkInUse ts-helper"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row m-t-20">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p class="c-black f-500 no-margin">Closing Date</p>
                <div class="input-group fg-float">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-calendar"></i></span>
                    <div class="dtp-container">
                        <input type="text" asp-for="ClosingDate" class="form-control date-picker" placeholder="Click here..." id="closingDate" name="closingDate" data-date-form />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
                <div class="input-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <input asp-for="Users" class="form-control" id="users" name="users" />
                        <label asp-for="Users" class="fg-label" for="users">Users</label>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Users" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row m-t-30">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn bgm-orange waves-effect mybtn">SAVE</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: provide your view code as well

Comment: @user9405863 I have posted the View

Comment: It is an existing project that I have started working on to add another module. I do not want to change how the functionality has been coded

Comment: When you use databinding to pass a form directly into a model at the controller, you need an input for each element of the model.  Try creating a hidden input on your view for the Software License Id.

Comment: I did that. Upon doing so, the `ModelState` became invalid and didn't allow me to insert/update data to database.

Comment: I did pass a hidden field. But, on doing so, my ModelState became invalid as on creating, I was not entering any value for the Id. I am not supposed to enter a specific value since it is primary key and has to be assigned automatically when data is entered into the database.

Comment: So you're "Create" can either create or update?  If that id field is an identity field and auto incremented when you create a new entry, it should probably be NULL, you are forcing it to have some value in your controller.  You want to pass a value for the id when you are updating an existing, which the hidden field does.  You need to address why you have a value at all for newly created entry.

Comment: Also, you'll need to check your IsValid method, as having an id should not fail the validity check when you are updating.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168756/discussion-between-lavahound-and-user7396598).

Answer (score 0):

When you use databinding to pass a form directly into a model at the controller, you need an input for each element of the model. Try creating a hidden input on your view for the Software License Id.

Your GET method is working because the actionlink, or whatever caller, is explicitly passing you an id value as a parameter.  You are then building your model by retrieving the object with that id, and passing it to the view.

You currently are not "storing" the software license id anywhere in your view, therefore it cannot be passed back to the controller through your POST call.

Comment: I did pass a hidden field. But, on doing so, my ModelState became invalid as on creating, I was not entering any value for the `Id`. I am not supposed to enter a specific value since it is primary key and has to be assigned automatically when data is entered into the database.

Comment: On checking why the Model is Invalid, I see that the error message is: `The value is invalid`

Comment: What is the value?  If you are creating a new entity it should be 0.  If it is zero, and failing the check, the check needs to be fixed

Comment: I understand. However, since I am using the same `View` for both `Create` and `Update`, I am not able to completely hide or show the hidden field. In other words, if I do not include the hidden field, then Update working, but Create not working. However, on including the hidden field, Create is working and Update is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not holding the value of variable that you get. Just keep this line inside your form tag and you issue will be resolved. This will keep the value of the variable preserved and you will get the value in post method.

```
     <input type="hidden" asp-for="SoftwareLicenseId"/>
```